# What's the difference between user experience and usability?

Tags: usability

Is there a difference? Does one fall under the other?

Comment: Please add to your question. As it is it's a duplicate of earlier questions.  To use a restaurant analogy - one can enter a restaurant, be seated, eat a meal, pay for it and have a horrible experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is an ejection seat handle

[image: Ejection seat handle]

It is engineered to be extremely **usable**.  The labeling is clear, communicative, and unmistakable, and the handle is large and ergonomic.

However, pulling it in a supersonic fighter jet doesn't provide a good **user experience**.  The pilot is very likely to escape the jet safely and survive, so the ejection system will have completed its function successfully and usably, but it is still not a good user experience.

Answer (score 2):

Usablilty means: **How easy** is your software/website to use. does everybody understand the concept directly or do you need to provide a manual?

User experience means: **how fun or exciting** is it to use your product.

## As an example imagine an alarm clock:

Good Usability: The alarm is easy to be set.

Good User experience: It wakes you up by using birds' twitter, soft music and emitting a warm light instead of using a sound like an abulance siren on a volume that will even wake your neighbors 3 blocks away.

I also think, that good usability is part of a good user experience, since you don't have a good time with a product, if it is not easy to use.